# How to serve static pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to serve static index.html page from "/" GET request in spring-web.

My module is included into bigger one, packaged as WAR and deployed to tomcat.

I've tried

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("WebMvcConfigurer - addResourceHandlers() function get loaded...");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/WEB-INF/classes/index.html")
                .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/classes/index.html");
    }
}
```

and placed index.html in resources folder. Still 404. Can anybody help me out with understanding what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern of the ResourceHandler should reflect the query path, in your case `/index.html`

Resources inside a jar/war `/WEB-INF/classes/` can be accessed via `classpath:`, in your case `classpath:/index.html`

So your config should have been like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/index.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/index.html");
    }
}
```

You can simplify if you have more resources with

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/");
```

Comment: worked for me: `registry.addResourceHandler("/static/index.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/");`